# how to save hashmap of objects to shared preferences

Tags: android, hashmap, sharedpreferences

I have a **hashmap** of **objects**.I want to save that to **shared** **preferences** and get it. How can I do this?

Comment: i have googled. But ddnt get a correct answer. If you know the answer please do post.it will be really helpful

Comment: Please try @seethalakshmi my answer may be working as it worked for me

Comment: Please have a look of my answer.

Comment: its clearly mentioned in my question that its a hashmap of objects.Normal hashmap i know to save to preferences

Comment: if some one know the answer please do post.I m sstuck with this

Comment: May i show you a code to Store a Custom Object with HashMap as Value in SharedPreference ? @seethalakshmi

Comment: AS i worked on your Question and developed one Demo So Please If you are avail then reply that May i show a code or not ? @seethalakshmi

Comment: @RajanBhavsar actually my question was that.Then why are you asking this now.I dont understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check As i added the full code of my MainActivity.java file as follows:

```
public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {

HashMap<String, Rajdata> map;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    map = new HashMap<String, Rajdata>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        Rajdata raj = new Rajdata();
        raj.setNamString("My Data" + i);
        map.put("MyData" + i, raj);
    }

    saveData(MainActivity.this, map);
    // Assign adapter to List

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void saveData(Context context, HashMap<String, Rajdata> mlist) {
    SharedPreferences shared;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

    shared = context.getSharedPreferences("MONDAY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = shared.edit();

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(mlist);
    editor.putString("mondAy", json);
    editor.commit();
    Fetchdata();
    // String getSaved = shared.getString("mondAy", null);
    /*
     * Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, getSaved,
     * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
     */

}

public void Fetchdata() {
    SharedPreferences shared;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    shared = getSharedPreferences("MONDAY", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    editor = shared.edit();
    HashMap<String, Rajdata> listDayItems = gson.fromJson(
            shared.getString("mondAy", null),
            new TypeToken<HashMap<String, Rajdata>>() {
            }.getType());
    printMap(listDayItems);

}

public static void printMap(HashMap<String, Rajdata> mp) {
    Iterator it = mp.entrySet().iterator();
    while (it.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry pair = (Map.Entry) it.next();
        System.out.println(pair.getKey() + " = "
                + ((Rajdata) pair.getValue()).getNamString().toString());
        it.remove(); // avoids a ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
}
```

And the Custom Rajdata class as follows:

```
public class Rajdata {

String namString;

public String getNamString() {
    return namString;
}

public void setNamString(String namString) {
    this.namString = namString;
}

}
```

Comment: @seethalakshmi Sorry For My Above comment Please look as i posted the code and please reply is it working or not.

Comment: @seethalakshmi Are you checked that code is it working ?

Comment: @seethalakshmi  Reply soon as i was worked on your Question for half an hour so please appreciate by your reply to me.

Comment: Thank you for your answer:) i will check it will let u know

Comment: i am getting null pointer exception when i am calling function to get the value from preferences

Comment: In My Code or in your code If That is in your code then please show me that code also @seethalakshmi

Comment: Please show me your code where you got null pointer exception may be i am able to helpful to you.@seethalakshmi

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81291/discussion-between-rajan-bhavsar-and-seethalakshmi).

Answer (score -2):

Please do something like this -

```
//variable for Shared preference.
        private SharedPreferences _sPrefs;
        private Editor _editorSpref = null;



        _sPrefs =getSharedPreferences("MYPREF", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        _editorSpref =_sPrefs.edit();


    // fetch data from HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<String, String>();
        Iterator myVeryOwnIterator = pairs.keySet().iterator();
        while(myVeryOwnIterator.hasNext()) {
            String key=(String)myVeryOwnIterator.next();
            String value=(String)pairs.get(key);
            _editorSpref.putString(key,value);
            _editorSpref.commit();
        }
```